# Php Multidimensional Array With Mixed For And Foreach Loops

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nested

I'm a beginner to PHP and am currently working on re-coding a small site from Classic ASP (VB) to PHP, and I was wondering if there was a fairly direct 'translation' in taking this concept from one to the other language?

I know that nested foreach loops would do the job, yet, I am curious if a for outer loop, with a foreach inner loop would work?

Here's what I've attempted to do.
For some reason, the variable $strMonth_Alpha does not return.
Thanks for any leads.

PHP Code:

```
$strMonthList='01,January;02,February;03,March;04,April;05,May;06,June;07,July;08,August;09,September;10,October;11,November;12,December';
$arrMonthList=explode(';',$strMonthList); //create the outer array
    //print_r(array_values($arrMonthList));
    for ($ii=0; $ii<count($arrMonthList); $ii++) {
        $M=explode(',',$arrMonthList[$ii]); //create the inner array
        //print_r(array_values($M));
        $myArrayCount=0;
            foreach($M as $a => $item) {
                    if ($myArrayCount==0) {
                    $strMonth_Num=$M[$myArrayCount];
                    //echo '<BR>$strMonth_Num...'.$strMonth_Num.'<BR>';
                    }

                    if ($myArrayCount==1) {
                    $strMonth_Alpha=$M[$myArrayCount];
                    }else{
                    $strMonth_Alpha='';
            $myArrayCount=($myArrayCount+1);
                 }  
            }
    }//to next month
```

Comment: Lots of code that doesn't do anything. What result do you expect anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Tried your code, nothing except formatting has been changed, just echoed the variable and I get value "December". Is this what you want ?

Just add this to the end of your code after last bracket.

```
echo $strMonth_Alpha;
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  I realize that after many hours, I missed the obvious and put the echo $strMonth_Alpha within the 'false' section of the if/then statement.  No wonder it would not print.

Answer (score 1):

`print($strMonth_Alpha)` within your code or print any other variables to debug and see where things are changing. I just tried printing this after your if/else statement and I get:

`print($strMonth_Alpha . '<br/>');`

```
January
February
March
April
May
June
July
August
September
October
November
December
```

Know that you are overwriting `$strMonth_Alpha` per loop.

If the data such as `01,January` is always in this format (i.e. an assumption that your code can safely make), then you can simplify your code to remove the second `for` loop.

```
$arrMonthList=explode(';',$strMonthList); //create the outer array
//print_r(array_values($arrMonthList));
for ($ii=0; $ii<count($arrMonthList); $ii++) {
    $M=explode(',',$arrMonthList[$ii]); //create the inner array
    echo($M[0] . "<br/>"); // num
    echo($M[1] . "<br/>"); // month name

}//to next month
```

Comment: Great approach!  That is very clean.  Regarding counting the elements of the array in the inner loop, could the use of the $a variable (in counting the array element) be just the same, in effect, as the counting variable ($myArrayCount), if the counting variable starts at zero?  I've tested it, and the results are the same, but I wasn't quite sure about how it operated within PHP.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but you already are using the count here: `count($arrMonthList)` which counts the number of entries (months) in your list, right? Or did you mean something else?